# Search for path of .exe

Tags: c++, windows, path

So I'm looking for a piece of code that allows me to search for the path of the file it's being executed in. For example, I'm doing an autorun program for use in pendrives (example) but I don't know if it'll end up as D:, F:, G: or whatever so the program would search it's own path and open another file based on the path he is found using some 'if' statements.

Here's what I thought:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main () {
    // Insert 'search path' code and needed variables here.

    if (-ThePath- == "d:\\AutoRun.exe")
        {
         system ("d:\\MyFolder\\OtherProgram.exe");
        }
    else if (-ThePath- == "f:\\AutoRun.exe")
        {
         system ("f:\\MyFolder\\OtherProgram.exe");
        }
    else if (-ThePath- == "g:\\AutoRun.exe")
        {
         system ("g:\\MyFolder\\OtherProgram.exe");
        }
    else
        {
         cout << "An error ocurred.\n";
         cout << "Press enter to exit...\n";
         cin.get();
        };
    return 0;
    }
```

Is there some way this could be done?

Comment: run this example and you'll get a pleasant surprise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx

Comment: Newer Windows versions have all but stopped supporting AutoRun. It's too risky, security-wise.

Comment: @MSalters - absolutely, AKA AutoMalware.

Comment: @nik.shornikov Ha, pleasant indeed. Thank you!

Comment: @MSalters Yes, you're right, however this is only an example. It might not be an AutoRun, but a simple program that'll open another inside a pendrive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetModuleFileName` : documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EDITED - Pedro, the sample code from Microsoft handles a lot of things. To get the file path, all you need is :

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

if( !GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH ) ) {

    // handle error in GetModuleFileName

} else {

    // now, szPath contains file path

};
```

Comment: Nice code, though it seems a bit too complicated to me at first sight. I'm still a beginner, been studying C++ for about half a year. I'll study it though, to improve myself :P Thanks for the share.

Comment: @PedroPellegrini: It's the correct answer, though. The WinAPI is indeed annoying, especially for C++ programmers who are used to real strings.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thank you, I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 2):

In standard C++ argv[0] contains the name of the executable. For a program invoked in the normal way this will be the path of the executable on Windows.

Comment: No, the standard states that « *`argv[0]` shall be the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the
name used to **invoke** the program or "".* » (3.1.6-2) Definitely not the full path.

Comment: Yep, saw that in nik.shornikov's link. Thank you for the answer.